# Block visibility of a text using a div?

Tags: css

I found this effect on material.io: https://material.io/gallery/

The Image is fixed and is overwritten by the blackish one, but the z-index must be smaller than it, because the first bg is covering it.
In my pov its only working, when another div, without any opacity, blocks the first image.
Is that somehow possiboe or are they using a different method?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This is similar to parallax but not exactly parallax. If you inspect the html,you will see that the image/svg section doesn't scroll but the text does. By giving the svg sections different z-index values this is possible. The images are different in different sections, it's just that those are not moving along with text so it appears as if the images are repeating.

I would suggest you to go through their css to get a better understanding.

This effect is called parallax effect. 
You can use a library like http://materializecss.com/parallax.html
to create it or you can create your own https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp

Comment: Their css is minified :(

Comment: You can inspect the element in your browser ( chrome or firefox) by right clicking and selecting inspect. I will suggest you to read about Chrome dev tools / firebug to get a better understanding of it.

Answer (score 0):

the two graphic elements are `position:fixed` each row that contains those graphics are incrementally positioned higher in the z-index and they have `overflow:hidden` set

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
section {
  height:100vh; position: relative; overflow:hidden;
}
section div {
  position:fixed; top:50%; left:100px; width:100px; height:100px; border:2px solid white; margin-top:-50px;
}
section.red { z-index:1; }
section.blue { z-index:2; }
.red { background:red; }
.blue { background:blue; }
```

```html
<section class="red">
  <div class="blue"></div>
</section>
<section class="blue">
 <div class="red"></div>
</section>
```

simplified example code: https://codepen.io/saetia/pen/mwBypp